# Multiple sales taxes in a sales receipt

Tags: quickbooks, accounting

I am using Quickbook online. I am trying to add multiple sales tax (Both state and county tax) in a sales receipt. But QBO only allows me to add only one tax. How can I add multiple tax rates in one receipt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both taxes are flat-rate percentages with no ceilings and are taxable on the same kinds of items, you will likely have to add the two percentages together.

If any of the above conditions are not true, you have a problem.  I write my own accounting software, so I am not first-hand experienced with QuickBooks.  Does it not allow any other kind of tax definition?  My Receivables package allows for multiple tax rates, but you can only apply one rate per line item on an invoice.

Another possible way to address this if all else fails is to enter the county tax as a separate line item on each invoice, which means you'd need to designate it as non-taxable, and calculate the amount based on the taxable items manually (with a calculator) and hope your software has an option to print a report for a specific transaction line item code.

Comment: Thanks Bill for your quick response. Yes, both the sales taxes have a fixed percentage. But when I am adding the state tax there is no line to add the county tax or vice versa. How can I add both the taxes in two lines so that they appear separately as sales taxes in the sales tax report?

Comment: You like will not be able to do it that way.  If QuickBooks has a specific Sales Tax Report, it will only recognize taxes recorded in their standard way, which it seems does not allow for multiple breakdowns.  In my proposed method, you would need to run a transaction report of sorts where you assign a specific transaction code to be used AS a sales tax for the county, which mean sit would not appear on the tax report, but at least you should be able to report it using other methods.

Comment: I found your answer.  Apparently Quickbooks does have something called a Sales Tax Group.  Google the phrase "quickbooks sales tax group" for details.

Comment: Thanks Bill. But I think Sales tax group is only applicable for QB, not for QB online.

Comment: Ah... see how clever they are?  They want you to buy Quickbooks, especially now that they've hooked you :)  I suggest that you contact someone at Intuit and explain your dilemma with them.  Perhaps there's an upgrade version that is still on-line that has the feature(s) that you need.  Good luck.

Comment: Yes. But they will charge money to upgrade. Is there any way I could add multiple sales tax in QB online?

Comment: Not likely.  I can tell you as a software developer myself that if a premium version of my software has a feature that I charge for, I'm not going to make it available for free in the other versions.  I still suggest you contact them directly, but don't get your hopes up.  You may have to resort to one of the alternatives I've posted.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks Bill for your help.